# MultipleChoiceField / CheckboxSelectMultiple values not restored on bound form

Tags: django

I'm building the 'edit' page of my form. This page is supposed to show form with the data that was saved, so the form is pre populated with saved data.
It works fine for most if the fields, but I have a problem with `MultipleChoiceField / CheckboxSelectMultiple` values that don't get restored. So instead of having the corresponding checkboxes checked with data from the saved form, they are all unchecked. Why is that ?

forms.py

```
class MemberForm( forms.ModelForm ):

    # ......

    MODEL_CATEGORIES = (
        ('advisor', 'advisor'),
        ('member', 'member'),
        ('admin', 'admin'),
    )


    model_categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            choices = MODEL_CATEGORIES
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = [ 'model_categories' ]
```

model

```
class Member( models.Model ):

    model_categories = models.CharField(
            max_length = 255,
            null = True,
            blank = True )
```

Controller

```
def profile_edit_form( request ):
    user = request.user or None

    # Get user member profile instance
    instance = get_object_or_404( Member, author = user )

    form = MemberForm( request.POST or None, instance = instance )

    context = {
        "form"    : form,
        "instance": instance
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        # ...
        return redirect( 'profile_display' )
    else:
        # Initial form display, and redisplay of invalid form
        return render( request, 'profile_edit_form_view.html', context )
```

Template

```
<form action="/accounts/profile-edit-form/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form }}


    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure why its not working but using initial would certainly work in the form

Comment: how would you use initial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as a 'feature' of Django, and won't get fixed:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28531

Solution is simple if you are using Postgres db, in your model, use an ARRAY field instead of a simple charfield:

```
    model_categories = ArrayField( models.CharField( max_length = 200 ), blank = True, null = True )
```

Multi select values are properly stored and restored from this type of model field, without the need of any data processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) in the form

```
form = MemberForm( request.POST or None, instance = instance, 
                                         initial={'model_categories': 'advisor'})
```

Comment: That's curious the value instance.model_categories is '[\\'advisor\\', \\'member\\']'. I believe this is the problem. When I manually pass ['advisor', 'member'] to the initial it works correctly.

Comment: well that could be the reason. form might not be able to understand which choice to take from available ones

Comment: for subject matter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values should be helpful  to you